# Solve transformation matrix. Convert Heisenberg representation to quantum computing state.

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a series of facts for known inputs and outputs of the form:

$U^\dagger.input.U = output$

(where $U^\dagger$ represents the conjugate transpose of unitary matrix $U$)

which procedure can be applied to determine $U$?

An example fact is:

$U^\dagger.(\hat \sigma_i \otimes \hat \sigma_z).U = \hat \sigma_x \otimes \hat \sigma_z$

In Matrix form this is:

$U^\dagger.\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}.U = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$

Here is the full set of facts for this example:

- input $\hat \sigma_x \otimes \hat \sigma_i$ output $\hat \sigma_z \otimes \hat \sigma_x$

  input $\hat \sigma_y \otimes \hat \sigma_i$ output $-\hat \sigma_y \otimes \hat \sigma_x$

  input $\hat \sigma_z \otimes \hat \sigma_i$ output $\hat \sigma_x \otimes \hat \sigma_i$

  input $\hat \sigma_i \otimes \hat \sigma_x$ output $\hat \sigma_i \otimes \hat \sigma_x$

  input $\hat \sigma_i \otimes \hat \sigma_y$ output $\hat \sigma_x \otimes \hat \sigma_y$

  input $\hat \sigma_i \otimes \hat \sigma_z$ output $\hat \sigma_x \otimes \hat \sigma_z$

The answer for $U$ in this manufactured example is:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1\\
1 & 0 & -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}
$

In Quantum Computing it represents an inverse bell measurement, which is a Hadamard gate followed by a CNot operation. The unitary transformation takes state $|00\rangle$ to state $|00\rangle + |11\rangle$. The objective of trying to find $U$ in the general case is to take a Heisenburg represenation of a state, which describes the relationship between qubits, and convert it to the ket state.

Comment: Does the following paper help? https://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.7366.pdf

Comment: Thanks. I don't see how it applies directly, although that is likely to be down to my lack of knowledge. I'll re-read a few times.